# www to non-www redirect not working using apache config or htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've placed the following lines in my apache config and in the .htaccess, but neither approach redirects to the non-www url.   I need the www url to go to the non-www url based on how the SSL cert is registered.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If the problem that you encounter is: "I get a giant warning screen and no redirect is made", then the problem is not fixable. For security reasons, the browser does not continue past finding out the certificate is invalid, and thus we have never the chance to redirect until the user continues past this screen. Just make sure every link on your site is without the www.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I was thinking that the apache redirect would occur prior to the browser evaluating the cert, but you're suggesting that it doesn't.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not fixable, other than making sure that all links to your site use `mydomain.com` instead of the www-variant. With https, during the handshake, the browser will verify the certificate that is being used. When it detects that the certificate is invalid, it won't continue with the request, because from that point on, the certificate can be of anyone, and thus the connection is not secure.

Long story short: Because the browser will not go through with the request, the server will never have the chance to issue a redirect. Only if the user clicks through, the request will be finished and the browser will continue with the redirect.